# SQL can't get head around logic

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I have a cricket database with the following schema:

```
Bowl(BowlID, MatchID, Striker, Non-Striker, Bowler, Runs, OverNum)
 - Stores info for every ball
Match(MatchID, Team1, Team2, Date)
 - Stores all the matches
```

I'm trying to work out what percentage of the penultimate balls of a match score a certain number of runs.

So first I need to get the penultimate balls of each match. Which I can't really work out how to do. The OverNum column stores the ball number, so for a twenty20 match this will start at '0.1' and go up to '19.6' (Assuming they lasted out the innings).

Would it be something like:

```
SELECT MatchID, MAX(OverNum) 
FROM Bowl 
WHERE OverNum 
NOT IN (SELECT Max(OverNum) FROM Bowl)
GROUP BY MatchID
```

I can't get my head around making sure that it takes the penultimate from EACH match, instead of the second highest OverNum from the whole bowl table...

Comment: How do you know if a match is 20-over one or a 50-over one?

Comment: Your inner select statement should be: `(SELECT Max(OverNum) FROM Bowl b2 WHERE b2.MatchID = MatchID)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to work out what percentage of the penultimate balls of a match score a certain number of runs.

Something in these lines:

```
SELECT 
    -- Consider each case where the runs scored on the
    -- penultimate ball is what you wanted as a '1' and rest as '0'
    (SUM(CASE Runs 
        WHEN @needed THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) * 100) / SUM(1),
FROM 
    Bowl b1
    JOIN 
    (
        // Penultimate ball in a given match.
        SELECT bNextMax.MatchId, Max(CONVERT(REAL, bNextMax.OverNum)) 
        FROM 
            Bowl bNextMax
            JOIN (
                SELECT MatchId, MAX(CONVERT(REAL, OverNum)) OverNum
                FROM Bowl 
                GROUP BY MatchID
            ) as bMax
            ON bNextMax.MatchID = bMax.MatchID AND bNextMax.OverNum != bMax.OverNum
    ) b2
    ON b1.MatchID = b2.MatchID AND b1.OverNum = b2.OverNum
```

Comment: Thanks, that gives me a good grounding for the percentage! However I think I'll use the comment below for getting the penultimate ball as that takes into account the case where the penultimate ball is ball 10.4. (Perhaps they only batted 11 of the 20 overs)

Comment: Right, that makes sense and I didn't take that into consideration while deducing the last ball.

Comment: @DuaneAllman, Updated my query to get the penultimate ball in a given match and then take the corresponding runs in the percentage calculation.

Answer (score 0):

To get the penultimate ball use this:

```
select *
from (
   select matchid, overnum,
          row_number() over (partition by matchid order by overnum desc) as rn
   from bowl
) t
where rn = 2;
```

You didn't mention the DBMS you are using. The above is ANSI standard SQL and is supported by nearly all modern DBMS.

Comment: I'm using HSQL (the openoffice base driver) through Java, is this supported?

Comment: @DuaneAllman: no, HSQLDB does not (yet) support windowing functions.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a slightly more complex inner query. I'm assuming you're using SQL Server of course, though Oracle might actually make this a bit easier.

```
select * from Bowl b
where OverNum = 
(
    select top 1 OverNum from 
    (
        select top 2 OverNum 
        from Bowl 
        where Bowl.MatchID = b.MatchID 
        order by OverNum desc
    ) top2 
    order by OverNum asc
)
```